# Evaluating an integral with a square root in the denominator of a fraction.

Tags: calculus, integration

Perform the following  integration:
$$ \int \dfrac{ 1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1} } \,\,  dx $$

Answer:

Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate. Let $\tan \theta = x$. We have:
\begin{align*}
dx &= \sec^2 \theta \,\, d\theta \\
I &=
 \int \dfrac{ 1}{\tan^2 \theta   \sqrt{ \tan^2 \theta +1} }
   \,\,   \sec^2 \theta \,\, d\theta \\
%
I &=
 \int \dfrac{ 1}{\tan^2 \theta  \sec \theta }
  \,\,   \sec^2 \theta \,\, d\theta \\
%
I &= \int \dfrac{ 1}{\tan^2 \theta  }
  \,\,   \sec \theta \,\, d\theta \\
%
I &= \int \left(\dfrac{1}{ \cos \theta } \right)
 \left( \dfrac{ \cos^2 \theta  }{ \sin^2 \theta } \right)  \,\, d\theta \\
%
I &= \int \cot \theta \csc \theta \,\, d\theta \\
I &= - \csc \theta + C \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to substitute back.
\begin{align*}
I &= -\dfrac{1}{\sin \theta} + C \\
\end{align*}
How do I finish the problem?
Using an online integral calculator I find the answer is:
$$ I = - \dfrac{ \sqrt{ x^2 + 1 } }{x} $$

Comment: Continuing your work, you just need to express $\csc\theta$ in terms of $x$. Recall that $\csc^2\theta=\cot^2\theta+1$ and hence $\csc\theta=\sqrt{\cot^2\theta+1}=\sqrt{(1/x)^2+1}$, now simplify. Do note that this all assumes $x\gt 0$ and we simplify the square roots $\sqrt{(\cdots)^2}$ as $\cdots$ instead of $|\cdots|$

Comment: Almost any integral is as described in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x>0$ we have

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \int \frac{dx}{x^3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

$$ = \int \frac{d\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{-2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}} = -\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+C$$

Pulling the $x^{-2}$ factor out allows us to say that the antiderivative is

$$-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} + C$$

for all $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get to the finish line using the substitution.

From $x = \tan \theta$, you can construct a right triangle whose hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{1 + x^2}.$ (This is just from using Pythagoras and your basic trigonometric ratios). Now based on that picture you've drawn. $\sin \theta = \ldots$ (finish this).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx = [u =-\frac{1}{x}] = \int \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^{2}}}du = \sqrt{1+u^{2}} +C= -\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+C.
$$

Comment: I thought about this way too.

Comment: But there is a sign problem...

Answer (score 0):

Let $y= \sqrt{x^2+1} $. Then $y’=\frac xy$ and
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\
 = &\ \int \frac{dx}{x^2 y}
= \int\left(y-\frac{x^2}y\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}
=\int\left(\frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{y’}x\right)dx\\
=&-\int d\left( \frac yx \right)=-\frac yx+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You got: $I=-\dfrac{1}{\sin \theta}+C$, where $\theta = \arctan x$.

Hence, it is:
$$I=-\frac{1}{\sin(\arctan x)}+C= -\frac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{\dfrac{\tan(\arctan x)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\arctan x)}}}+C=\boxed{-\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}+C}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach based on hyperbolic functions:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}} & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(\sinh(u))}{\sinh^{2}(u)\sqrt{1 + \sinh^{2}(x)}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\cosh(u)}{\sinh^{2}(u)\cosh(u)}\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sinh^{2}(u)}\\\\
& = \int\operatorname{csch}^{2}(u)\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = -\coth(u) + C\\\\
& = -\frac{\cosh(u)}{\sinh(u)} + C\\\\
& = -\frac{\sqrt{1 + \sinh^{2}(u)}}{\sinh(u)} + C\\\\
& = -\frac{\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}}{x} + C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is similar to Hunaphu's solution. I considered sign (negative/positive) situations.

İf we sub $x=\frac1t$ in $\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ we get,
$\begin{align}\int-\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt&=\int-sgn(t)\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt\\
&=-sgn(t)\sqrt{t^2+1}+c\\
&=-sgn(t)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{|x|}+c\\
&=-\frac{sgn(t)}{sgn(x)}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+c\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}+c
\end{align}$

Since $sgn(t)=sgn(x)$.